# How can I select hero products to appear 1st in a catergory

Tags: category, configurable-product, category-products

We have products we want to appear first but are not the newest products added. How can we select these individual products to appear before others. A selected hierarchy of products within a category

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by changing products position on the Category edit page: Admin > Catalog > Categories > Select a category to edit > tab Products in Category.

Select Visibility (`Catalog` or `Catalog, Search`) as your site setup, in most cases, it will be Catalog, Search. Then change the positions as you need, the lowest value of the position will be displayed first, and the highest position will be displayed last.